# how can I display total record in below table?

Tags: vue.js, quasar-framework, quasar

I have a issue to display the total row in quasar/vue. I cannot get the totalRecord. I tired to run, but no errors, any idea to display the totalRecord??

```js
<script>
import { ui } from "../ui-helpers/ui";
import * as cu from "../_services/cu";
import {
  required,
  decimal,
  minValue,
  maxValue,
  requiredIf
} from "vuelidate/lib/validators"
import moment from "moment-timezone"
import Vue from "vue"
import { uid, date } from "quasar"
import MessageBox from "../components/MessageBox"

export default {
  data() {
    return {
      filter: "",
      mode: "list",
      scDefinition: require("../statics/translate.json"),
      currencyColumns: [
        {
          name: "name",
          align: "left",
          label: "Name",
          field: "name",
          sortable: true
        },
        {
          name: "code",
          required: true,
          label: "Code",
          align: "left",
          field: "code",
          sortable: true
        },
        {
          name: "buyRate",
          align: "center",
          label: "Buy Rate",
          field: "buyRate",
          sortable: true
        },
        {
          name: "spotRate",
          align: "left",
          label: "Spot Rate",
          field: "spotRate",
          sortable: true
        },
        {
          name: "sellRate",
          align: "left",
          label: "Sell Rate",
          field: "sellRate",
          sortable: true
        },
        {
          name: "symbol",
          align: "left",
          labelalign: "left",
          label: "Symbol",
          field: "symbol",
          sortable: true
        },
        {
          name: "status",
          align: "center",
          label: "Status",
          field: "status",
          sortable: true
        }
      ],
      currencyData: [
        {
          name: "Malaysian Rinngit",
          code: "MYR",
          buyRate: "4.097(-2.5%)",
          spotRate: "4.19",
          sellRate: "4.238(+0.5%)",
          symbol: "RM",
          status: "Active"
        },
        {
          name: "Singapore Dollar",
          code: "SGD",
          buyRate: "xxxx(-2.5%)",
          spotRate: "x.xx",
          sellRate: "x.xxx(+0.5%)",
          symbol: "$",
          status: "Active"
        },
        {
          name: "Chinese Yuan",
          code: "CNY",
          buyRate: "xxxx(-2.5%)",
          spotRate: "x.xx",
          sellRate: "x.xxx(+0.5%)",
          symbol: "¥",
          status: "Active"
        },
        {
          name: "Malaysian Rinngit",
          code: "MYR",
          buyRate: "4.097(-2.5%)",
          spotRate: "4.19",
          sellRate: "4.238(+0.5%)",
          symbol: "RM",
          status: "Active"
        },
        {
          name: "Singapore Dollar",
          code: "SGD",
          buyRate: "xxxx(-2.5%)",
          spotRate: "x.xx",
          sellRate: "x.xxx(+0.5%)",
          symbol: "$",
          status: "Active"
        },
        {
          name: "Chinese Yuan",
          code: "CNY",
          buyRate: "xxxx(-2.5%)",
          spotRate: "x.xx",
          sellRate: "x.xxx(+0.5%)",
          symbol: "¥",
          status: "Active"
        }
      ],
      pagination: {
        page: 1,
        pageSize: Number(process.env.VUE_APP_REPORT_RECORD_PER_PAGE),
        rowsPerPage: Number(process.env.VUE_APP_REPORT_RECORD_PER_PAGE)
      },
      page: 1,
      totalRecord: 0,
      pageCount: 1,
    }
  },

  methods: {
    async fetchData(newSearch = false) {
      if (newSearch) {
          this.page = 1
        }
      this.totalRecord = 0
  
      var response = await cu.getValue(
        this.pagination.pageSize,
        this.page
      )

      if (response.Page != null) {
        this.totalRecord = response.Page.total_record
      } else {
        this.totalRecord = response.currencyData.length
      }
      this.pageCount = Math.ceil(
        response.Page.total_record / this.pagination.rowsPerPage
      )
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

```html
<template>
  <q-page padding>
    <q-table
      flat
      bordered
      class="statement-table"
      title="Currency"
      :data="currencyData"
      :hide-header="mode === 'grid'"
      :columns="currencyColumns"
      row-key="name"
      :grid="mode == 'grid'"
      :filter="filter"
      :pagination.sync="pagination"
    >
      <template v-slot:top-right="props">
        <q-input
          outlined
          dense
          debounce="300"
          v-model="filter"
          placeholder="Search"
        >
          <template v-slot:append>
            <q-icon name="search" />
          </template>
        </q-input>

        <q-btn
          flat
          round
          dense
          :icon="props.inFullscreen ? 'fullscreen_exit' : 'fullscreen'"
          @click="props.toggleFullscreen"
          v-if="mode === 'list'"
        >
          <q-tooltip :disable="$q.platform.is.mobile" v-close-popup>{{
            props.inFullscreen ? "Exit Fullscreen" : "Toggle Fullscreen"
          }}</q-tooltip>
        </q-btn>

        <q-btn
          flat
          round
          dense
          :icon="mode === 'grid' ? 'list' : 'grid_on'"
          @click="
            mode = mode === 'grid' ? 'list' : 'grid';
            separator = mode === 'grid' ? 'none' : 'horizontal';
          "
          v-if="!props.inFullscreen"
        >
          <q-tooltip :disable="$q.platform.is.mobile" v-close-popup>{{
            mode === "grid" ? "List" : "Grid"
          }}</q-tooltip>
        </q-btn>
      </template>

      <template v-slot:body-cell-status="props">
        <q-td :props="props">
          <q-chip
            :color="
              props.row.status == 'Active'
                ? 'green'
                : props.row.status == 'Inactive'
                ? 'red'
                : 'grey'
            "
            text-color="white"
            dense
            class="text-weight-bolder"
            square
            style="width: 85px"
            >{{ props.row.status }}
          </q-chip>
        </q-td>
      </template>
      
      <template v-slot:bottom>
        <div class="pagination-total q-mt-sm flex flex-center">
          <div class="text-medium-regular">
            Total {{ totalRecord }}
            <span v-if="totalRecord > 1">results</span>
            <span v-else>result</span>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="pagination-container q-my-sm flex flex-center">
          <q-pagination
            v-model="page"
            color="secondary"
            :input="true"
            :max="pageCount"
            :max-pages="6"
            @input="fetchData(false)"
            :boundary-numbers="true"
          />
        </div>
      </template>
    </q-table>
  </q-page>
</template>
```

The output of image show the total Record still 0
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/EbYzw.png

This is the Codepen:
[Codepen]:https://codepen.io/Adriantango/pen/MWymeEQ